# Contact details from the supplier page returns "None" even when it is present

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

This is my code for extracting supplier Information via different pages. I have been trying to get the Company name, contact details etc. from the each of the supplier url on each page. But the contact returns the value "None". And therefore adding .text method gives the error:
"None" type object has no attribute "text".

I have checked the headers for my browser compatibilty. As I have been using google chrome(85.0.4183.102). But the value returned is still "None".
what could be the issue? I am stuck over here.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


base_url="https://idn.bizdirlib.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'}
supplierlinks=[]

for x in range(1,2):   #Loop through all the pages 
    response=requests.get(f"https://idn.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/946?page={x}",headers=headers)  
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
    supplierslist=soup.find_all("div",class_="views-field views-field-title")
    
    for element in supplierslist:   #Looking through each of the items
        for link in element.find_all("a",href=True):    
            supplierlinks.append(base_url+link['href'])

Database=[]
for link in supplierlinks:
    r=requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    companyname=soup.find_all("span", attrs={"itemprop": "name"})[-1].get_text()    
    country=soup.find_all("span", attrs={"itemprop": "location"})[-1].get_text()
    address=soup.find_all("span", attrs={"itemprop": "address"})[-1].get_text()
    #print(soup.select_one('strong:contains("Contact") + *').text )
    contact=soup.find("span",attrs={"itemprop": "contactPoint"})
    #print(soup.select_one('strong:contains("Contact") + *').text )


    
    
 #Prepare a dictionary to store all of it
    data= {"Company Name":companyname,
              "Country":country,
              "Address":address,
              "Contact Person":contact
    }

    Database.append(data)
    
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `itemprop` `contactPoint` does not exist in the page you are querying. I think the item might be optional or you have mistakenly interpreted the HTML of the page you are scraping.

Comment: Yes. In some pages, the contact person is not available. So, should I use error handling to avoid it and get the remaining contacts?